# Display Probability with Geom_Tile?

Tags: ggplot2

I'm trying to fill a 20x20 grid randomly according to a given probability. For example, if I was given a probability of 67%, I would want to fill a random 268 squares with blue, and leave the other ones empty.

Can anyone help me with this? Appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

```
win.prob <- .67
heatmap <- matrix(ifelse(runif(400, min = 0, max = 1)<=win.prob,1,0), nrow = 20)
heatmap.m <- melt(heatmap) %>% mutate("Majority" =     ifelse(value>0.5,"Democratic","Republican"))


library(reshape)

ggplot(heatmap.m, aes(x = X1, y = X2,fill=Majority)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Democratic" = "blue","Republican"="red"))
```